# ms access / sql server syntax (i guess)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, outer-join

this query:

```
SELECT sentmails.[VersandDatum], 
       sentmails.[DatumMailGeplant], 
       mailintervals.[Interval], 
       definitions.[Subject], 
       users.[Name], 
       sentmails.[MailArt], 
       Objekte.[Name], 
       sentmails.[Erledigt], 
       sentmails.[ID]
  FROM Objekte 
RIGHT JOIN (users RIGHT JOIN (definitions RIGHT JOIN (mailintervals RIGHT JOIN (sentmails) ON mailintervals.ID=sentmails.Intervall) ON definitions.ID=sentmails.Noti_ID) ON users.UID=sentmails.Funktion) ON Objekte.OId=sentmails.Objekt_ID
```

...works fine in ms access qbe, but in sql server it returns a "incorrect syntax near ')'" error.  I'm really wondering why:

- the joins need to be in brackets?
- no more outer joins in sql server?
- somewhere more brackets needed?

Answer (score 1):

Your `JOIN` syntax is incorrect. You should be joining each table individually, without nested parentheses. You probably want something like:

```
SELECT sentmails.[VersandDatum]
    , sentmails.[DatumMailGeplant]
    , mailintervals.[Interval]
    , definitions.[Subject]
    , users.[Name]
    , sentmails.[MailArt]
    , Objekte.[Name]
    , sentmails.[Erledigt]
    , sentmails.[ID]
FROM Objekte
RIGHT JOIN sentmails ON Objekte.OId = sentmails.Objekt_ID
RIGHT JOIN users ON users.UID = sentmails.Funktion
RIGHT JOIN definitions ON definitions.ID = sentmails.Noti_ID
RIGHT JOIN mailintervals ON mailintervals.ID = sentmails.Intervall
```

[Here's a starting point in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

MS Access has a slightly different JOIN syntax. Use this instead:

```
SELECT 
    sentmails.[VersandDatum], 
    sentmails.[DatumMailGeplant], 
    mailintervals.[Interval], 
    definitions.[Subject], 
    users.[Name], 
    sentmails.[MailArt], 
    Objekte.[Name], 
    sentmails.[Erledigt], 
    sentmails.[ID]
FROM Objekte 
RIGHT JOIN sentmails ON Objekte.OId=sentmails.Objekt_ID
RIGHT JOIN definitions definitions.ID=sentmails.Noti_ID
RIGHT JOIN mailintervals ON mailintervals.ID=sentmails.Intervall
RIGHT JOIN users ON users.UID=sentmails.Funktion
```

Comment: just trying sqlstr.Replace("RIGHT JOIN", "RIGHT OUTER JOIN").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "") 
and it seems to be getter better